# Why do I get an error when geting values from a jfreechart dataset?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a method for updating a DialChart that lool like this...

```
public void updateDatasetSPLmaxSample(double newValue) {
    double currentValue = (double)(datasetSPLmaxSample.getValue()); //ERROR THIS LINE
    if (newValue > currentValue) {
        this.datasetSPLmaxSample.setValue((int)currentValue);
    }
}
```

However, for some reason I get the following error:

*Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double*

`datasetSPLmaxSample.getValue()` returns a java `Number` so casting it to a double like I do shoudn't be a problem as far I know, but it is. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.Number` is the abstract superclass of both `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.Double`, but casting between such *sibling* classes is [not permitted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.12). As your dataset contains instances of `Number`, you can use the `doubleValue()` method.

```
double currentValue = datasetSPLmaxSample.getValue().doubleValue();
```